# Prove that if $x,$ $y,$ and $z$ are integers such that $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ , then $3$ divides $xy.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that if $x,$ $y,$ and $z$ are integers such that $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ , then $3$ divides $xy.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Are you familiar with modular arithmetic?

Answer (score 4):

For any $a \in I$, $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or  $a^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$

---

If $x^2$ or $y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ then we are done.

Therefore, $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $y^2 \equiv 1\pmod 3$ but then $z^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ which is impossible

Answer (score 0):

A formula for generating any Pythagorean triple is
$$x = m^2 - n^2$$
$$y = 2mn$$
$$z = m^2 + n^2$$
Suppose that $y$ is not a multiple of 3. Then $x$ must be a multiple of 3. Assume that $m > n$. Then if $y$ is not a multiple of 3, then neither is $m$ nor $n$. Assume that $m = 3a + 1$ and $n = 3b + 1$. Then $$m^2 - n^2 = 9(a^2 - b^2) + 6(a - b)$$ which is a multiple of 3. The other three cases can be proven similarly (i.e. $m = 3a + 1$ and $n = 3b + 2$, or $m = 3a + 2$ and $n = 3b + 1$ or $m = 3a + 2$ and $n = 3b + 2$).

Comment: That is only the formula for $fundmental$ triples.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet yes, but if it not a fundamental triple then you simply divide by the GCF, and the result still holds.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Euclids Formula: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Proof_of_Euclid's_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Proof_of_Euclid%27s_formula)

To say $x=mn$ and $y= \frac{(m-n)(m+n)}{2}$ for some positive integers $m,n$. Therefore $xy=\frac{mn(m-n)(m+n)}{2}$. From this we can deduce that:

$$xy \equiv 0 \text{ (mod 3)} \leftrightarrow mn(m-n)(m+n) \equiv 0 \text{ (mod 6)}$$

The right hand side can be shown trivially case by case.